# Cannot see what is in design preview on android studio?

Tags: android

This is how Android Studio looks for me:
[image]

When I pick a number text and put it on a blue screen, I cannot see it to edit it. Why is that?

Comment: paste your xml code there. is any colored view on top of other views?

Comment: you should post your xml code of layout design

Comment: Welcome to the stackoverflow. Check this guide on how to ask good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

At the very top where it says Pixel XL (to the left of it). To the right of the refresh icon.

You have 3 different boxes. The box in the middle is all blue, see it? great. Click on the box on the left that has zero blue. What do you get now?

Comment: Thanks, I fix by changing the version of Android Studio from canary to astable version.